# Text to vim-quickfix with navigation

Tags: vimscript, quickfix

`LaTeX`, being a markup language, is very hard to grammar-check. I found one program, that do this exactly [Textidote](https://github.com/sylvainhalle/textidote). Problem is, this is a standalone program and, for example, this latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
How is you?
I is fine.
I am fine.
\end{document}
```

shows error:

```
 java -jar ~/bin/textidote.jar --check en_UK --output singleline i.tex 
TeXtidote v0.8.1 - A linter for LaTeX documents and others
(C) 2018-2019 Sylvain Hallé - All rights reserved

Found 2 warning(s)
Total analysis time: 3 second(s)

i.tex(L7C5-L7C7): The pronoun is must be used with are>.. Suggestions: [are] (4) "How is you?"
i.tex(L8C3-L8C5): Did you mean am>?. Suggestions: [am] (14) "I is fine."
```

My question is, is there some way that I convert this output to a quickfix list (with press `n` to go to next error)?

Comment: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/compiler/textidote.vim

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg: Thanks a lot. I know your project supports `Textidote`, unfortunately I am a LaTex-Suite user. Do you think I can use textidote.vim as an independent plugin?

Comment: Yes, I think you can use this file as an independent plugin. It is a compiler plugin so you should read the docs for that, e.g. `:help :compiler`.

Comment: Hello @KarlYngveLervåg: I am trying to use textidote, using VimTex, and make textidote| lmake is just writing this in quickfix window, without any navigation, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q2ePwxTDnZIhV2NRmW8arpwhVJgVc60X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on the github repo. It's hard to discuss and help in the comment field on SE.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to set `'makeprg'` and `'errorformat'` to appropriate values, and then do `:make`. Output is loaded into the quickfix list, which you navigate with the usual commands.

Further, putting these settings in a compiler plugin allows faster use: if you create `~/.vim/compiler/textidote.vim` with the right contents, you can do

```
compiler textidote
make
```

[A solid-looking compiler script](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/compiler/textidote.vim) has been posted in the comments.